# Emacs Predictive - Accept with punctuation

Tags: emacs, code-completion, predict

I have successfully managed to install the predictive package for Emacs and am trying to accept the most likely correction with punctuation, which is mentioned in the manual:

http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/Auto_002dCompletion-Mode.html

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set this up, I have tried the code snippet, among others (in my .Emacs):

```
(custom-set-variables
'(auto-completion-syntax-alist (quote (accept . word))))
```

And while Emacs does not complain, auto-completion-mode is off when he code is included.

When opening a file, I can see that it does not scan for auto-overlays, when the above code is in my .emacs file.

The rest of my predictive .emacs related file looks like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/")
;; dictionary locations
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/latex/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/texinfo/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/html/")
;; load predictive package
(autoload 'predictive-mode "predictive.el" t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'predictive-mode)

 (setq predictive-main-dict 'dict-english
   predictive-predictive-use-buffer-local-dict t
   predictive-auto-learn t
   predictive-auto-add-to-dict t
   predictive-dict-autosave t)
```

Comment: Sure it must scan for overlays? Did you install the dictionaries?

Comment: No, I am not sure, but when it does not scan it does not work. The dictionaries are installed, as predictive mode works perfectly fine when the above mentioned code snippet is not included in my .emacs init file.

Comment: So maybe do not include it?

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, I'd suggest asking Toby Cubitt, the creator of *Predictive*.  Wait a bit, though, as you might get an answer here.